# Joining Data that don't overlap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I am working on a project where I am classifying different types of shorelines in the Hudson River near Manhattan. My adviser is interested in seeing the depth changes along the different shorelines. The depths are a raster so I used the Raster to Point tool and then used the Spatial Join Tool (Analysis Tools-Overlay-Spatial Join Tool) to join the depths (to the shoreline classification attribute table) that intersect with the shorelines.

However, I need to find out the depths of the shorelines that don't quite intersect with the shoreline (bathymetry data was taken by a boat so most of the depth data does not intersect with the immediate shoreline).

Is there a near function tool where I can get the depths near each shoreline?

I have attached a screen shot to give you an idea of what I am talking about.

[image: Bathymetry and shoreline classifications]

[image: MAP]

Comment: There's a `Near` tool under `Analysis Tools -> Proximity`, which will grab the nearest single point from each line (assuming your shorelines are line features). Another idea, could you create a buffer around your shoreline and then `Extract by Mask` to get all depths within that buffer?

Comment: Awesome, thanks I will give this a try. The shoreline features are polygons but I can convert them to lines. Thanks again.

Comment: It will work on any type of feature (including polygons).

Comment: This just gives me the distance. I need the depth value associated with the closest shoreline

Comment: What exactly are you going to do with the depth data? (i.e., why are you trying to join it to the shoreline polygons?) If we figure out your ultimate goal we can probably better answer your question.

Do you just want a bunch of points along the shoreline that include depth information?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Near](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) tool under `Analysis Tools -> Proximity`, which will grab the nearest single point from each line or polygon.

You can use the `Match Option` parameter in the `Spatial Join` tool to join to the `CLOSEST` point.
[image]

Comment: This just gives me the distance. I need the depth value associated with the closest shoreline

Comment: Do you want each polygon to inherit the depth of the closest point?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do. Thanks for the help guys